# Routing from inside router outlet in angular 2

Tags: angular, router

I'm starting an app and I'm using routing in Angular 2. I have a topbar with a login form, and when the users log in successfully it changes the route, but when the user does not exists it routes to the login form. Here, when it logs in well, the route is not working, does not change (I'm using the same method for both log in forms).

Here is part of the code:

Login form (does not route when submit, it appears inside the router-outlet when the login fails)

```
<form role="form" (ngSubmit)="login()">
  <!--log in form -->        
</form>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent{
 constructor(private loginService: LoginService){}

  private model: any = {};

  public login(){
    this.loginService.login(this.model);
  }
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService{
  login(credentials: any){

    //hardcoded just to test
    if (username == "admin" && password == "admin"){
      localStorage.setItem("currentUser", "admin");
      this.router.navigate(["home"]);
    }
    this.router.navigate(["login"], {queryParams: {error: true}});
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? It's a bit unclear to me :)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to explained it as best as possible. The problem that is not routing, the router-outlet view does not change when I submit that form